# c++ _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS warning

Tags: c++

when i run the program then came a warning .
what is this warning in visual studio `C4996: '_swprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe.` Consider using `_swprintf_s` instead. To disable deprecation, use `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the warning says, it's more safe to use _swprintf_s instead. The _s function require the size of the buffers and are therefore more safe against buffer overruns.

Answer (score 0):

right click on your project name, then, select "Configuration..."->"C/C++"->"Command Line", add " /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS " in the "Additional Options"